# Apply Function to Specific Column in R List

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I have seen many questions pretty similar to mine, but none of the answers I've seen have actually solved what I'm trying to do. I have a list of data frames, and I'm trying to apply the `digest()` function to the same column in each data frame in my list. A couple of the answers I've seen on SO to this have been:

```
dflist <- list(data.frame(number = 1:10, name = 1:10),
               data.frame(number = 2:15, name = 1:14))

dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x){
  x$name <- digest(x$name, algo = "sha256")
  return(x)
  })

#OR this

dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {
  x %>% mutate_each(funs(digest(.,algo = "sha256")), "name")
})
```

Both of these give the same output - which is simply every row in the `name` column having the same exact value. The `digest()` function works but only returns the value of the first row, in every row.

I've also tried:

```
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {
  digest(x[,"name"], algo = "sha256")
  })
```

But this just returns only the first value from each data frame in the list.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `digest` is not vectorized

```
dflist1 <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {
      x$name <- Vectorize(digest::digest)(x$name, algo = "sha256")
     x
   })
```

Or use it in `transform`

```
dflist1 <- lapply(dflist, transform, name = Vectorize(digest::digest)(name))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for teaching me something new!